# all goroutines are asleep - deadlock issues

Tags: go, deadlock, channel, goroutine

I am trying to print odd-even numbers in synchronized manager (1,2,3,4...) with two goroutines, I am confused why my code leads to a deadlock. please could you help me to understand?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func odd(ch chan bool){
    i :=1
    for i<=10{
        <-ch
        fmt.Println(i)
        i+=2
        ch<-true
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func even(ch chan bool){
    i :=2
    for i<=10{
        <-ch
        fmt.Println(i)
        i+=2
        ch <- true
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    ch :=make(chan bool)
    wg.Add(2)
    go even(ch)
    go odd(ch)
    ch <- true
    wg.Wait()

}
```

> O/P: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 fatal error: all goroutines are asleep -
> deadlock!
>
> goroutine 1 [semacquire]: sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x5844a8)
> /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x45
> sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x5844a0)
> /usr/local/go-faketime/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x65 main.main()
> /tmp/sandbox505861393/prog.go:37 +0xcf
>
> goroutine 6 [chan send]: main.even(0xc00005e060)
> /tmp/sandbox505861393/prog.go:26 +0xc5 created by main.main
> /tmp/sandbox505861393/prog.go:34 +0x7f

when I change the order of goroutines then o/p starts printing in an even-odd manner, I am also trouble with understanding that. I would appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that both sending and receiving on a channel is blocking? As your error output already tells you, one of the goroutines gets stuck on sending since the other goroutine has already terminated and there is no-one that receives on the channel anymore.

Comment: As a side-note. You should not send and receive on a channel from the same goroutine.. It's not considered good practice.

Answer (score 1):

First, your two goroutines need to receive from `ch` channel to start work

```golang
for i<=10{
        <-ch // wait until receive
        fmt.Println(i)
        i+=2
        ch <- true
    }
```

So you send a value to `ch` channel to make your two goroutines work

```golang
func main() {
    //...
    ch <- true
    //...
}
```

But this won't work as expected, because your two goroutines share the same `ch` channel. When `ch <- true` in `main()` executed, only one of them can receive, start work, and send a value back to `ch` channel.

After that, two goroutines continually receive from `ch` channel, start work and send a value back to channel

In other words, two goroutines send and receive values from each other by using `ch` channel

```golang
for i<=10 {
    <-ch           // receive when main() executed at first time, after that receive from another goroutine
    fmt.Println(i) // start work
    i+=2           //
    ch <- true     // return back to the channel, another goroutine will receive it
}
wg.Done()
```

But the problem is when one goroutine exited, the remaining goroutine still try to send to `ch` channel after work, but there is no receiver, this causes a deadlock

Answer (score 1):

Sending on a channel will also block if there is no space in channel. If you use buffer in channel then send can work. Use just 1:

```
ch := make(chan bool, 1)
```

Now you can send data and it will not block the go routine as it is not full. If you send again without reading then it will block the send call as again there is no space and previous value is still not consumed.

About the order of printing: There is no ordering in which go routine will start first and go lang specs does not mention if multiple go routines are receiving data from a channel then whether the [one waiting first really gets it first](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator). So you need to add additional sync to maintain the order if that is required. [Here is hint for ordering sync](https://riptutorial.com/go/example/6056/ping-pong-with-two-goroutines).

Below is modified code that prints but I would prefer different approach. Check the ping - pong example in link above where 2 separate channels are used instead of one.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func odd(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan bool) {
    defer wg.Done()
    i := 1
    for i <= 10 {
        <-ch
        fmt.Println(i)
        i += 2
        ch <- true
    }
}

func even(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan bool) {
    defer wg.Done()
    i := 2
    for i <= 10 {
        <-ch
        fmt.Println(i)
        i += 2
        ch <- true
    }

}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan bool, 1)
    defer close(ch)
    wg.Add(2)
    go even(&wg, ch)
    go odd(&wg, ch)
    ch <- true
    wg.Wait()

}
```